# Set Div Width to Background Image Width Css?

Tags: html, css

Is there a pure css way of setting your div width to the width of the background image you are using for that div?

for instance right now I'm doing this...

```
#homeNav{

    background-image:url(../images/navPieces/home.jpg);
    width:165px;
    text-align:right;

}
#aboutNav{

    background-image:url(../images/navPieces/about.jpg);
    width:81px;
    text-align:center;

}
#competitorsNav{

    background-image:url(../images/navPieces/competitors.jpg);
    width:117px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I'd love to NOT have to write in the width of every div.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nav? Are you sure that those shouldn't be gif or png? Jpeg is a bit ... lossy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there isn't.  The CSS doesn't know the width of specified background images. You could do it with a bit of Javascript that preloaded the images and then set the div widths.

Comment: Indeed. I'd rather just live with it than trying to go around it with JS. That's what you get paid for.

Comment: Bummer.  I guess css doesn't do EVERYTHING I ever wanted.

Answer (score 4):

What I did :

- set the backgound-image to the div with url(urlsrc)
- add an img to the div with src=urlsrc
- get img size with .width() and .height()
- remove the img
- set css width and height of the div to the width and height precedently calculated

Ugly, but it works :p

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
    object-fit: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.parent1 {
 background-image: url("https://www.image-engineering.de/content/products/charts/te169/images/TE169.jpg");
}

.transparent-img{
    max-height:360px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
 
<div class="parent parent1" id="homeNav">
   <img class="transparent-img" src="https://www.image-engineering.de/content/products/charts/te169/images/TE169.jpg">
 </div>
```

Nice hacky answer was provided by oued but here is what I did with pure CSS.

You set your backgorund-size property to contain and not repeat. You set background-url as separate class on same parent element.
Then you set opacity to 0 for image that will be inside parent element.
This way your div will fallow width of transparent image and your background image will be shown and it will scale nicely.